# Is it possible in web page to "slide" a section on top of the other using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-transitions

I want to use CSS3 transition to add some effect to my web page. Basically, i want to make one specific section to slide on top of another one.

For example i have the following page:
[image]

And i want it to look like the following when i hover on top of a section like the following:
[image]

Here the code used:

```
                <div class="polar">
                <div class="flt-sec-left">
                    <a href="index.html" class='left'>home</a>
                    <section>
                    <p> Our offers are the best on the city !! Check out our amazing activities !!! </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="flt-sec-right">
                    <a href="_web/playa.html" class="inv">La Playa !</a>
                    <section class='inv'>
                <p> One of the best in the world, if not the best, garanty !!! </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="polar">
                <div class="flt-sec-left">
                    <a href="_web/ciudad.html" >La Ciudad !</a>
                    <section>
                <p> Feel what your granpa felt in his youth, back to the fifties baby !! </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="flt-sec-right">
                    <a href="_web/excursion.html" class="inv">La Excursion !</a>
                    <section class='inv'>
                  <p> I thought pirate of the carabbean was all a hollywood set up. No ! We got it all wrong !! </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
         </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.polar
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.flt-sec-left
{
    width:50%;
    float:left; 
}
.flt-sec-right
{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
.flt-sec-left:hover
{
z-index:1;
    width:50%;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.flt-sec-right:hover
{
    position:absolute;
z-index:1;
    width:50%;
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

So i want my home section to slide on top of la playa section(now it is just pushing it and forcing it to go down on the page).

Is it possible to do so using floating techniques (just using CSS and HTML).

Thanks.

Comment: And do you have HTML? Or a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could see?

Comment: HTML. I'll edit the questions to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `z-index:` and `position: absolute` attributes.

References: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [here](http://www.css3.com/css-position/). *Hint 'absolute'.*

Now for the transitions I would recommend that we head right back over to the friendly lads at w3schools: 
However depending on specifically *how* you want the section to "slide" over the other, you may prefer to use an animation rather than a transition.

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

As was mentioned above, if you provide a jsfiddle of the current code you're using it would allow me, and everyone else, to be more specific.
Specificity yields results.